# Is there any way to dynamically convert a Jenkinsfile into a Drone.yml pipeline configuration?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, yaml, drone.io

I currently have some existing Jenkinfiles from an older Jenkins CI/CD pipeline configuration. I've started migrating services to Drone CI recently but not quite sure how some of the Jenkins (groovy) commands translate to Drone's yaml syntax.

Example (redacted / sample):

```
// ...
stage('version')
  choice = new ChoiceParameterDefinition('VERSION', ['x', 'y', 'z'] as String[], '...')
  def type = input(id: 'type', message: 'Select one', parameters: [choice])

stage('Tag') {
  sh "./some-script/.sh -t ${type}"
}
// ...
```

Is there anything that could do the conversion automatically? The DroneCI docs are pretty vague and don't cover many important pipeline design aspects (at least not from what I've found).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is impossible to achieve in DroneCI by the same means. This is because Jenkins allows entering input from the UI when running a pipeline, while DroneCI does not.

You can however specify properties such as the version number in a different file that the pipeline can identify and process accordingly.